# ATI Radeon 5850 infinite beep, no post, no video

Tags: amd-radeon

I recently got an Visiontek Radeon 5850.  On installation with the one 6-pin PCIe adapter inclulded, I got no post, no video, and an infinite beep from the card.  Posting this question so I can answer it in hopes that someone else finds it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply wasn't getting enough power.  I purchased another Dual Molly 4 pin to 6 pin adapter and jumped out a second PSU.  I now have one PSU running the computer and another running the card.  And it works, runs fairly stable.

When I say runs well, I mean Crysis 2 with all settings on extreme and the card is a little overclocked.